# Ford Edge wheel bounce when slightly turning left

Tags: wheels

I drive a 2007 Ford Edge and when I get to 40-50mph I experience a wheel shake on the front driver when slightly turning left. Also when I get to about 70mph the ABS and Traction control Lights come on. I know it isn't the tires or rims. I know it could be wheel bearings,shocks, or rotors, but I can't seem to pinpoint the issue. No play in the tire when lifted either. Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's a front wheel drive, it's almost certainly a cv joint.  Get it fixed soon as they can break and strand you.

Comment: Yes the car is fwd

Comment: Does the cv joint have anything to do with the abs and tcs coming on or is it unrelated

Comment: The only reason why I think its not a cv joint is because when i make a full turn i dont get any poping or noise.

Comment: it definitely can.  The sensor on some cars reads how fast the cv spins by a cog-like pattern formed on it.  This is a pic of a ford:  http://image.made-in-china.com/43f34j00UeIaHlvbgdoT/CV-Joint-Accessory-ABS-Ring-for-Ford-Tooth-Type.jpg  look at the ridges.  The sensor is right there.  If there is excessive vibration, it will read incorrectly and throw an error.  It could also have a crack.

Comment: it causes vibration because there could be a bad spot and it binds in that spot while swiveling.  If you turn sharper, it's possible because of the way they are made that it's not swiveling on the bad spot.  It IS possible however that the problem could be a crack in the rotor, but the ABS / traction control lights definitely point at it being the cv joint.  It isn't a very expensive part btw.  I had both of mine replaced recently on my Focus and they were $65 for the entire axle.

Comment: Thanks a lot John! hopefully everything works out when i get it replaced

Comment: you're welcome.  Note that that doesn't include labor, but it's not terribly hard to replace them yourself if you have air tools.  You have to remove the strut from the a-frame to give you clearance to remove the spline.